# How are images handled in Microsoft Word

Tags: java, ms-word

I am trying to embed images in xml document and save the document as a single document and be able to distribute the file just like microsoft word where both the text and images are saved in single docx file.

How is it done in Microsoft word. Do they use base64 encoding ?

Comment: A docx actually is a zip file, rename it as .zip and have a look. It also contains XML content.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to do it by hand and would look something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" 
            xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" 
            xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" 
            xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:body>
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:drawing>
          <wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0">
            <wp:extent cx="5943600" cy="3717290"/>
            <wp:docPr id="1" name="Picture 0" descr="vlcsnap-325726.png"/>
            <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
              <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                  <pic:nvPicPr>
                    <pic:cNvPr id="0" name="myImage.png"/>
                    <pic:cNvPicPr/>
                  </pic:nvPicPr>
                  <pic:blipFill>
                    <a:blip r:embed="rId4"/>
                    <a:stretch>
                      <a:fillRect/>
                    </a:stretch>
                  </pic:blipFill>
                  <pic:spPr>
                    <a:xfrm>
                      <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                      <a:ext cx="5943600" cy="3717290"/>
                    </a:xfrm>
                    <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                      <a:avLst/>
                    </a:prstGeom>
                  </pic:spPr>
                </pic:pic>
              </a:graphicData>
            </a:graphic>
          </wp:inline>
        </w:drawing>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

You don't want to do it that way. I would recommend to use an external library like [OpenXML SDK 2.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) (by Microsoft) or [OpenXML4J](https://poi.apache.org/oxml4j/) (especially for Java). They will make your life way easier